# Converting data attribute in Rails from HTML to HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, nested-attributes, custom-data-attribute

I have to add a data attribute to a div with the class search-wrapper, which in HTML looks like this:

However the page I need to do this to is in HAML. I'm having some trouble figuring out exactly what the nature of this tag translate to in HAML to convert it. So far the closest I can get is:

```
  .search_wrapper {:data-slideout-ignore => true}
```

This looks close, but isn't passing. Could someone clear this up?

Answer (score 1):

This got answered over slack: `.search-wrapper{ data: {  slideout: { ignore: true } } }`